# Is there a PHP function to format a currency amount in accounting format?

Tags: php, currency, string-formatting

I'm currently writing a report in PHP that occasionally has to display negative currency amounts. Said currency amounts are stored in the database like "-44.00". Ideally this number would be output as "($44.00)" on the report.

I know I can write some semi-complicated function to detect whether the number is negative and manually insert the parenthesis, but I was wondering if there was some handy PHP function that can do this for me before I re-invent the wheel. I've searched around and have not found anything that seems to do this exact task. I know about money_format, but I don't see any way to do the negative/parenthesis part. Keep in mind the code has to function whether the number is negative or positive.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

```
echo money_format('%(n', '-44.00');
```

Comment: Upon trying this, it does not add the dollar sign. I've read the documentation for money_format and am still not seeing a way to add the dollar sign.

Comment: For clarification, if I call "money_format('%(n', $row['paymentamount'])" when paymentamount is 100, it returns (100.00)

Comment: @DWilliams, you can write your own print_money_format($amount) rather easily. PHP is an international language and supports many currencies, it would be sort of silly if it printed a $ by default, even sillier to require another argument (and break existing implementations) by making you specify the currency symbol :)

Comment: @tinkertim I think that is what setlocale is for...to set the currency. Says it's supposed to add the $ on php.net, but i cannot get it to do so. Not sure what the deal is.

Comment: `%n` is the flag that controls whether the currency symbol is displayed.  Maybe make sure that your app is setting the locale?

Comment: Since I'm Canadian: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_CA'); echo money_format('%(n', '-44.00');` produces `($44.00)` or `$44.00` (if positive) as expected.

Comment: Danger! `money_format()` is not cross-platform. It doesn't exist on Windows. And on Linux/OS X, locale names can vary. See `locale -a` for supported locales on your system. I had to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, array('en_CA.utf8','en_CA.UTF-8'));` to work on both OS X and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

```
function format_currency($amount) {
    if($amount < 0)
        return "($".$amount.")";

    else return "$".$amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sort of...but that would still output the minus sign when it is negative. I would change that function to be something like:

```
function accting_format($amount) {
    if ($amount < 0) return '($' . abs($amount) . ')';
    return '$' . $amount;
}
```

Notice the abs() around the amount is the parentheses have already been outputted.