# php: format currency without thousand separator

Tags: php, currency

In an international web app, we deal with currencies like this:

USD: 2,400.55
EUR: 2.400,55

I need to be able to print those number as 2400.55 (for usd) and 2400,55 (for EUR)
The problem is that I don't know in advance what kind of currency is coming at me.

No matter what the number format is, I'd like to use a function that only strips out the thousand separator, no matter if that is a , or a .

The number_format didn't solve my issue as far as I could see.
Any tips on this?

Comment: How is the application supposed to change the money value if you don't give it the input currency?

Comment: Don't you gonna say that these numbers being stored in the `2,400.55` format, do you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i print currency format in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013950/how-do-i-print-currency-format-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a PHP function to format a currency amount in accounting format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625717/is-there-a-php-function-to-format-a-currency-amount-in-accounting-format)

Comment: *(tip)* [Devzone: I10n in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4799)

Comment: everything is stored unformatted as 2500.55 in the database

Comment: so, your question is just how to replace a dot with comma? Great. That's what I call logic

Comment: @Gordon, your link is not a duplicate, because in that question the asker *wants* the thousands separator.  In this question the asker wants to avoid it.

Comment: @finnw It is a duplicate because the solution is the same. StackOverflow does not need one question for every possible combination of arguments you can pass to a function. People should learn to read an API and how to abstract. The question is about internationalization and not just about adding or removing a separator.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I know how to format currencies in php. I couldn't and still can't find a decent way to remove the thousand separator as the money_format function doesn't exist on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function for that.

**Note:**

> The LC_MONETARY category of the locale
>   settings, affects the behavior of this
>   function. Use [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) to set to
>   the appropriate default locale before
>   using this function.

Comment: I coded it with the money_format function, by passing the locale to it and by stripping the thousand separator with the ^ option.

Comment: Sorry, guys, this function is not supported on windows and crashes the application. I'm looking for an alternative here.